# how to use std::function to point to a function template

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

```
#include <functional>

int func(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

int main()
{
    typedef std::function<int(int, int)> Funcp;
    Funcp funcp = func;

    return 0;
}
```

But is it possible to point to a template function?

```
#include <functional>

template<class T>
T func(T x, T y)
{
    return x + y;
}

int main()
{
    typedef std::function<?(?, ?)> Funcp;
    Funcp funcp = func;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No. A template function is exactly that, a template. It's not a real function. You can point a std::function to a specific instantiation of the template function, e.g. `func<int,int>`

Comment: +1. Really, the term "template function" is misleading, "function template" is more accurate.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it's a little misleading. You say 'no', then go on to explain why the answer is 'yes, if you instantiate it.'

Comment: @leviathanbadger You're missing the point though. Once you do that, it now only supports int, as opposed to any type that fits the interface. In otherwords, you can't use templates, only instantiation. That is a massive difference.

Answer (score 31):

There is no such thing as a *template function* in C++ — what people casually mention as "template functions" are actually *function templates* : templates which define functions.

As such, `func` in your second example above is not a function, it's a (function) template, and it cannot be used in the same way as a function can. In particular, `std::function` expects to be provided with a function.

How you can work around this depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you're trying to make the code that uses the function work with any type, you can simply place that code in a function or class template:

```
template <typename T>
void use_function(T t) {
  typedef std::function<T(T,T)> Funcp = func<T>;
  // use Funcp here
}
```

What you will not be able to do, however, is use late binding with universal type quantifiers ("can be applied to any type"), because "can be applied to any type" is necessarily resolved at compile-time in C++. That's just how it rolls.

Answer (score 19):

Is this what you want?

```
#include <functional>

template<class T>
T func(T x, T y)
{
    return x + y;
}

template<typename T> struct FunctionType
{
    typedef std::function<T(T, T)> Type;
};

int main()
{
    FunctionType<int>::Type Funcp = func<int>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Erik points out, this is not possible directly. To achieve the effect you probably desire, you would have to make the code that uses the pointer a template.

Answer (score 0):

*this resolution may be a little tricky.*

supposed you want calling function with a specified key(pair type),
you may indexing the func ptr in following 2 ways:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

enum A {
    RGB=3, YUV=2, GRAY=4
};

template<A t, A tt>
void f() {
    cout << "default" << endl;
    cout << t << endl;
    cout << tt << endl;
}

template<>
void f<A::RGB, A::YUV>() {
    cout << "spec rgb -> yuv" << endl;
}

template<>
void f<A::YUV, A::RGB>() {
    cout << "spec yuv -> rgb" << endl;
}

template<>
void f<A::YUV, A::GRAY>() {
    cout << "spec yuv -> gray" << endl;
}


int main()
{
    f<YUV,RGB>(); // yuv -> rgb
    std::vector<std::pair<std::pair<A,A>, std::function<void()>> > vec;
    vec.push_back(make_pair(make_pair(A::RGB, A::YUV), f<A::RGB,A::YUV>));
    vec.push_back(make_pair(make_pair(A::YUV, A::GRAY), f<A::YUV,A::GRAY>));
    vec.push_back(make_pair(make_pair(A::YUV, A::RGB), f<A::YUV,A::RGB>));
    auto functor = vec[0].second;
    functor(); // rgb->yuv
    
    for (auto iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); iter++) {
        if (iter->first == make_pair(A::YUV,A::GRAY)) {
            (iter->second)(); // yuv -> gray
            break;
        }
    }
    
      std::map<std::pair<A,A>, void(*)()> mmap;
    mmap.emplace(make_pair(RGB, YUV), f<RGB,YUV>);
    mmap.emplace(make_pair(YUV, GRAY), f<YUV,GRAY>);
    
    mmap[make_pair(YUV,GRAY)]();
    return 0;
}
```