# declaring templated function as argument to non-templated function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

```
template<typename Type>
void execute(absl::string_view expected_name){
  std::cout << "*** expected type: " << expected_name
            << " | actual type: " << typeid(Type);
}

void handle(std::function<void(absl::string_view)> executor){
  executor<int>("int");
  executor<double>("double");
}
```

I have this piece of code (which, of course, didn't compile).
I want to be able to pass a templated function to a "normal" function and have the "normal" function define the concrete type as it needs, as shown in the example.

Is there a way to declare on the `handle` parameter list that `executor` is a templated function?

Comment: you cant pass templates as parameters to functions, you cant even have an instance of a template. You probably want `handle` to be a template too

Comment: Might be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153148/how-to-use-stdfunction-to-point-to-a-function-template

Comment: If that was possible, I think you could come up with cases where you [edit: or the compiler] wouldn't be able to know which templates to instatiate before the execution.

Comment: @user463035818 `handle` being templated wouldn't solve the problem, would it? Even if I made `handle` templated, it still wouldn't change the fact that `executor` isn't declared to be templated

Comment: at some point you need to choose the parameters to instantiate `executor`. Either you do this directly at `handle` or the caller of `handle` decides

Comment: you should include the error message in the question, maybe I am just confused about what you actually want to do

Comment: Yes, I want handle() to choose the parameters of executor, NOT its caller.

Comment: If `handle` is a template function, it can accept a template parameter which is itself a template.  "template template parameters" are fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But `handler()` must receive necessarily a `std::function`?

If you can pass a `struct` with a template function in it, say

```
struct executor
 {
   template <typename T>
   void func (std::string_view const & sw) const
    { execute<T>(sw); }
 };
```

you can write `handler()` as follows

```
void handle (executor const & ex)
 { ex.func<int>("int"); ex.func<double>("double"); }
```

Comment: The simple solutions are always the best. Very clean. +1

Comment: Sure, this would work. But I didn't want to have to define an additional structure. Here you're wrapping a function inside a struct. C++ allows passing a function first class object, so I can't see why we can't make that work

Comment: @OneTwoThree: He's not wrapping one function in a struct, but an entire function template, which defines a family of functions.  A function pointer may be a first class object, but the family of functions produced from a template, is not.

Comment: @OneTwoThree - unfortunately a template function isn't an object but a set of objects; you can select one of they and pass it as argument of a function, but you can't pass the whole set of functions. The `struct` trick avoid this problem and pass a single object with the whole set of functions inside it.

Comment: And even for the "template template parameter" approach I mentioned in a comment, the template has to be a template class, not a template function.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/15651488/103167